# Count from associate table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, count

I want to have some stats from my app, `User` can publish post that I call `Idee`, and I want to know how many user have publish at least one idee.
I'm assuming that should be something like:

```
@total_user_active = User.where(idee.size >= 1).count
```

But this doesn't work.
It's `user` who is in table `idee` so maybe I should count how much unique `user_id` are in this column but how?

Comment: "idee" is column in users table. right?

Comment: No, it's user who is in idee table, so maybe I should count from the idee table how much user appear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
@total_user_active = Idee.distinct.count(:user)
```

Comment: why that `having` part ?

Comment: @suslov This is `Idee.distinct.count(:user)` correct,